# MPU6050 ESP32 No Acknowledge

Tags: arduino, i2c, esp32, logic-analyzer

I am struggling to get an acknowledge from the [MPU6050](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf) using ESP32 with Arduino framework. I am unable to derive if the problem is hardware or firmware.

I have copied [Sparkfun's breakout board schematic](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/IMU/Triple_Axis_Accelerometer-Gyro_Breakout_-_MPU-6050_v12.pdf), setting the FSYNC, CLKIN and AD0 pins to GND and SDA, SCL and INT to GPIOs 25, 26 and 27 respectively (INT is unused/floating). I am using 2.7 kΩ pull-ups for the I2C lines.

[image]

I am using the following code to test the I2C comms:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
 
#define I2C_SDA 25
#define I2C_SCL 26

void setup() {
  Wire.setClock(100000UL);
  Wire.begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL);
  delay(3000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("\nI2C Scanner");
}
 
void loop() {
  byte error, address;
  int nDevices;
  Serial.println("Scanning...");
  nDevices = 0;
  for(address = 1; address < 127; address++ ) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    error = Wire.endTransmission();
    if (error == 0) {
      Serial.print("I2C device found at address 0x");
      if (address<16) {
        Serial.print("0");
      }
      Serial.println(address,HEX);
      nDevices++;
    }
    else if (error==4) {
      Serial.print("Unknow error at address 0x");
      if (address<16) {
        Serial.print("0");
      }
      Serial.println(address,HEX);
    }    
  }
  if (nDevices == 0) {
    Serial.println("No I2C devices found\n");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("done\n");
  }
  delay(5000);          
}
```

I have probed the I2C line using a logic analyser. The code behaves as expected but I get no acknowledge.
[image]

I have checked that the chip has power, lowered the speed from 200 kHz (default) to 100 kHz. I have tried using internal pull-ups on ESP32 instead of external. I have tried a different MPU6050 chip.

Any help diagnosing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your schematic doesn't show any voltage source being connected to the MPU-6050 VLOGIC pin** (just a decoupling capacitor connected there).

However the VLOGIC pin must be connected to a suitable voltage source, as it is used by the digital I/O part of the MPU-6050. Without that, the I2C I/O won't work (as you have seen).

Typically VLOGIC would be the I2C supply voltage, where 3.3 V and 1.8 V are common standards, depending on what else is on the I2C bus. In your case (although your schematic doesn't show everything) I think you are running the I2C bus at 3.3 V so just connect VLOGIC to your VDD for the MPU-6050.

From the [MPU-6050 datasheet](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf):

[image: Explanation of VLOGIC input]

---

On the Sparkfun schematic, you can see there is a net label `VIO` on the VLOGIC pin, which goes to the VIO terminal on the Sparkfun board's header. That must be connected to a suitable voltage. This seems to not be well-documented by Sparkfun (surprisingly for them) and this omission is mentioned in a review on their [product page](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11028), which says:

> I didn't see anything in the provided documentation from Sparkfun about having to connect the VIO line to a 3V3 source as an IO Reference voltage. This should be documented better.

Comment: Well spotted! I have connected VLOGIC to VDD and I2C communication now works!

Comment: @WillPowell - Great news :)